# How is expansion of the Universe consistent with the speed of light?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, faster-than-light

I have a question that I believe is related to @PetTaxi's question here: [How far has a 13.7 billion year old photon travelled](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148079/), but I didn't want to hi-jack it.

My issue is this.  I'm assuming the most distant objects in the observable universe are 46 B light years away.  A photo from one of these galaxies has been traveling 13.7B years.  I assume the galaxy that emitted the photon was 13.7B light years away at the time the photon was emitted.  So, the problem for me is, the galaxy is now 46B light years away which implies in my mind that the galaxy moved 32.3 B light years (the difference in where it was versus where it is now) in only 13.7B years.  But of course, that can't be true because it would mean faster than light travel.

So, how does a galaxy get that far away in such a short time?  There is likely something fundamental here I don't understand about how the universe is expanding....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Are Galaxies Receding Faster Than Light Visible To Observers?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107748/)

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26549/2451 and links therein.